# Passing argument function not working

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

```
valid()
{
 if [[ "$1" = "0" ]]; then
        echo "Pass a file name as argument"
        exit 1
 fi
}

valid
if [ -f $1 ]; then
        echo "$1 exists"
else
        echo "$1 doesnt exist"
fi
```

In the above example, the **vaild()** function is not working, why so? When a valid argument is passed it checks the file name and prints but when not passed, it prints "exists".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check for `null` strings when taking a string as argument and not compare it with 0. You also need to pass the argument to the valid function.

```
valid()
{
 if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        echo "Pass a file name as argument"
        exit 1
 fi
}

valid $1

if [ -f "$1" ]; then
        echo "$1 exists"
else
        echo "$1 doesnt exist"
fi
```

Comment: I tried it, it is not working, the program exits with "Pass a file as argument" even if I pass one

Comment: Which shell are you using? I tested this using bash by passing a filename and without an argument and it works as expected. Could you maybe post your errors?

Comment: `./test_arg.sh fr

Pass a file name as argument`
I am using bash. Passing an argument `fr`also printing the same.

Comment: Do you have any `^M` or any typo's in your script? Could you update the question with your latest script and the corresponding output?

Comment: @san1512, you are not passing the argument to the `valid` function. See my answer to pass the argument to the `valid` function - `valid $1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79210/discussion-between-rahul-and-san1512).

Comment: To be picky, quote the argument: `valid "$1"`.  Also, `-f` tests to see if the object is a FILE, not that it does or does not exist (could be a directory).

Comment: ... and it is "doesn't", not "doesnt".

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `if [[ "$1" = "0" ]]; then` you can simply change it to:

```
if [[ "$1" = "" ]]; then
```

and it will work as expected.

And you need to double quote your variables inside `[ ]` syntax too. `[[ ]]` syntax can handle white spaces without needing any double quotation, but `[ ]` can't.

Comment: I tried with if `[[ "$1" = "" ]]; then` still the output is same.  @jahid

Comment: I get the output `"Pass a file name as argument"`, you sure you haven't done any other mistakes...?